# Error copying object to Realm

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to update a `RealmObject` but I keep getting the following error log:

```
Cannot copy an object from another Realm instance.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy an object from another Realm instance.
    at io.realm.RealmList.copyToRealmIfNeeded(RealmList.java:261)
    at io.realm.RealmList.add(RealmList.java:190)
    at com.radioafrica.music.activity.AudioPlayer$1.execute(AudioPlayer.java:193)
    at io.realm.Realm$1.run(Realm.java:1187)
    at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityRunnable.run(BgPriorityRunnable.java:34)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The code to update the object is:

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    Favorite favorite = realm.where(Favorite.class).findFirst();

                    favorite.getTracks().add(getCurrentTrack());
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(favorite);
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(AudioPlayer.this, "Added to favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage(), error);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: Clearly, you're copying an instance to the Realm that is managed by another Realm instance. The relevant code from `(AudioPlayer.java:193)` would help.

Comment: What @EpicPandaForce is saying. Each Realm instance is defined by its RealmConfiguration. Apparently you are trying to copy data from one configuration that belongs to another.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I am using the same `RealmConfiguration` defined in the `Application` class.

Comment: What is **getCurrentTrack()**

Comment: @EpicPandaForce its a method returns the currently playing track object.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's probably a managed Realm object that belongs to another Realm instance.